# node.js child process change a directory and run the process

Tags: node.js, bash, process, external

I try to run external application in node.js with child process like the following

```
var cp = require("child_process");
cp.exec("cd "+path+" && ./run.sh",function(error,stdout,stderr){
})
```

However when I try to run it stuck, without entering the callback

run.sh starts a server, when I execute it with cp.exec I expect it run asynchronously, such that my application doesn't wait until server termination. In callback I want to work with server.

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

cp.exec get the working directory in parameter options
http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Use

```
var cp = require("child_process");

cp.exec("./run.sh", {cwd: path}, function(error,stdout,stderr){
});
```

for running script in the "path" directory.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are interpreted by the shell, you cannot see them if you just look at `ps` output.